# org.apache.axis2.description is missing in java code

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I have to write Java program who call Web Service, I have the wsdl file.
So, I generate Java class from wsdl with Eclipse and Axis2Wizards functionalities.

All my files have the following error:

> org.apache cannot be resolved to a type

I understand that some org.apache.axis2.* libraries are missing, but I don't know where to find them and how install them.

Comment: You can find the required libraries here : http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/modules/index.html

Comment: Thanks,I downloaded the axis2-1.6.2 Library and add all the .jar files to my eclipse project as 'Referenced Librairies'.